# csv to xml not adding xElement if XAttribute = ""

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've create an xml file from a csv file like this

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String[] FileContent = File.ReadAllLines(csvPathFile);
            String XMLNS = "";
            int idCountProduct = 1;
            XElement Inv = new XElement("data",
                from items in FileContent
                let fields = items.Split(';')
                select new XElement("category",
                    new XAttribute("idCategory", fields[0]),
                    new XAttribute("CategoryName", fields[1]),
                    new XElement("products",
                        new XElement("product",
                            new XAttribute("IdProduct", idCountProduct++),
                            new XAttribute("Rif", fields[0]),
                            new XAttribute("ProductName", fields[2]),

                            new XElement("products",
                                new XElement("product",
                                    new XAttribute("IdProduct", idCountProduct++),
                                    new XAttribute("Rif", fields[0]),
                                    new XAttribute("ProductName", fields[3]),
                                    new XElement("products",
                new XElement("product",
                    new XAttribute("IdProduct", idCountProduct++),
                    new XAttribute("Rif", fields[0]),
                    new XAttribute("ProductName", fields[4]));
            File.WriteAllText(xmlPathFile, XMLNS + Inv.ToString());
        }
```

this is my csv file

```
1;Beverages;Lemon Juice;;Orange Juice
```

this is the xml file i want to create

```
<data>
<category idCategory="1" CategoryName= "Beverages">
    <products>
      <product IdProduct="1" Rif="1" ProductName= "Lemon Juice" />
      <product IdProduct="2" Rif="1" ProductName= "Orange Juice" />
<products/>
<category/>
</data>
```

and this is the xml file i obtain

```
<data>
<categories>
<category idCategory="1" CategoryName= "Beverages">
    <products>
      <product IdProduct="1" Rif="1" ProductName= "Lemon Juice" />
      <product IdProduct="2" Rif="1" ProductName= "" />
      <product IdProduct="3" Rif="1" ProductName= "Orange Juice" />
<products/>
<category/>
<categories/>
</data>
```

How can I avoid adding a product if ProductName is not assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a filter to your LINQ query to filter out empty products:

```
where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(fields[4])
```

just after this:

```
let fields = items.Split(';')
```

Anyway if your condition is so simple you do not even need it and you may filter out entries from the Split instruction itself:

```
let fields = items.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

**EDIT**
Your code is pretty fixed so...are you sure you need to use LINQ and LINQ-to-XML? I guess it'll be even more readable anyway...write this:

```
        XElement data = new XElement("data");
        XDocument document = new XDocument(data);

        int counter = 0;
        foreach (string entry in File.ReadAllLines(csvPath))
        {
            string[] fields = entry.Split(new char[] { ';' },
                                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            XElement category = new XElement("category",
                new XAttribute("idCategory", fields[0]),
                new XAttribute("CategoryName", fields[1]));
            data.Add(category);

            XElement products = new XElement("products");
            category.Add(products);

            for (int i = 2; i < fields.Length; ++i)
            {
                products.Add(new XElement("product",
                    new XAttribute("IdProduct", counter++),
                    new XAttribute("Rif", fields[0]),
                    new XAttribute("ProductName", fields[i])));
            }
        }

        document.Save(xmlPath);
```

}

Comment: Thanks but this way, even my Category isn't print to xml. I woul like having category even if there aren't products associated.

Comment: If your category is the first column in the CSV then it won't be splitted out if you use StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries.

Comment: I'm using your where condition after let clause. I need a where condition that hits only products. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated the answer, see sample code (it works for any number of product, you do not need to hard-code their number)